# git new branch, points to previous one

Tags: git

I am creating new branch from develop:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

then when running status command I see:

> On branch new-branch Your branch is ahead of 'develop' by 2
> commits.

why its pointing to develop ?
Even my zsh shows it weird:

```
new-branch:develop
```

git push does not work, it shows that my branch is update to date, but git push origin really pushes to new-branch. Not sure that had happened.

Comment: At minimum we have to know: What are the 2 commits you did under which branch and pushed to which repo. When was the new branch created and how is the branch develop related to it. Are there other commits involved, maybe by other authors... the messages you show simply says nothing...

Comment: it happens just after creating new branch.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the answer, few days ago I did:

```
git config --global branch.autosetupmerge true
```

which is causing this..

just rolledback it to

```
git config --global branch.autosetupmerge false
```

and no issues at all

Comment: You must have set it to `always`, because the default `true` setting means *set it if and only if the start-point name supplied on the command line is a remote-tracking name*. `develop` is a branch name (local branch, but "local" is redundant here since remote-tracking names aren't branch names); `origin/develop` would be a remote-tracking name, and hence would cause this with `git checkout -b new-branch origin/develop`.

Comment: A better setting, for most users, will be `git config --global branch.autosetupmerge simple`, or the default `git config --global branch.autosetupmerge true` as @torek outlines. Setting it to `false` will make things more complicated for you later in many cases where you would expect to have a tracking relationship, and be able to easily push and pull, but instead have to explicitly specify the upstream.